# How to configure VSCode on Linux to make it apply different JAVA_HOME for Gradle in different projects?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, gradlew, java-home

Right now I have a Spring project (needs Java 17) and a minecraft-forge-1.12 project (needs Java 8) on the same system.

I want vscode to automatically change JAVA_HOME between `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64` and `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` for gradlew command when I switch between these two project.

I tried using `.vscode/settings.json` to do that, but `java.import.gradle.java.home` cannot change in `settings.json`, so I can't change this for Gradle.

Is there a way doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up the `Java runtime` separately for your project workspace.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> pen the control panel and select **Preferences:Open Workspace Setting(JSON)**

  [image]
- Add the following configuration to the **settings.json** file

```json
// Just an example, please modify it to your own path

    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-8.0.332.9-hotspot",
            "default" : true,
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.3.7-hotspot",
        }
    ],
```

- Change `"default" : true` for different workspace.

Comment: If you used a build tool, please modify it in the corresponding script(like `pom.xml`).

Comment: For gradle, how should i modify it? the `sourceCompatibility` in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Ok now, i solve the rest with add```"terminal.integrated.env.linux":{
        "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
    }```